# PHP I don't know what difference end() makes in an array

Tags: php

```
$fruits = ['apple','cranberry','banana','cranberry'];
end($fruits); 
$last_key = key($fruits);

var_dump($fruits[$last_key]) // result : cranberry
```

```
$fruits = ['apple','cranberry','banana','cranberry'];
$last_key = key($fruits);

var_dump($fruits[$last_key]) // result : apple
```

As you can see, the results of the two codes are different.
It seems to be the difference in the return value of end(), so I looked up the documentation.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

they said "Returns the value of the last element or false for empty array."
If it's like this i wondered if it was a parameter difference.

Parameters:
"The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference."

I think I've found the answer...(...it is modified by the function.) but...
When I var_dump($fruits), there is no difference in value.

```
var_dump($fruits);
```

I do not understand it well...I'm sorry, but can explain in detail?

Comment: PHP arrays keep internal cursors (current position) and using `end()` moves the cursor to the last index. From the documentation you linked... _"**end()** advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value."_

Answer (score 0):

The **end()** function is an inbuilt function in PHP and is used to find the last element of the given array. The **end()** function changes the internal pointer of an array to point to the last element and returns the value of the last element.

```
<?php
   
  // Input array
  $arr = array('X', 'Y', 'Z');
 
  // end function print the last
  // element of the array.
  echo end($arr);
 // Output - Z
?>
```

Another example

```
<?php
 
  // Input array
  $arr = array('1', '3', '4');
 
  // end function print the last
  // element of the array.
  echo end($arr)."\n";
 
  // end() updates the internal pointer
  // to point to last element as the
  // current() function will now also
  // return last element
  echo current($arr);
  

?>
```

**Output - 4**

**4**